# ResponseEntity Coming as null in Resttemplate JUNIT Call

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, junit5

Writing JUNIT-5 for a GET REST Call 
My actual implementation is like  below and its working fine.

```
ResponseEntity<OrderDocument> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
URL,HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<>(headers),OrderDocument.class,
message.getPayload().toString());
responseEntity.getBody() // Null pointer Exception when calling from JUNIT
```

My Full implementation of JUNIT is below

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class OrderMasterClientImplTest {

@Autowired
OrderMasterClientImpl orderMasterClient;
private ConsumerMessage consumerMessage;
private EventMessage eventMessage;

@MockBean
@Qualifier("orderMasterRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@MockBean
ResponseEntity responseEntity;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
    eventMessage = objectMapper.readValue(
            this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                    "event_message.json"),
            EventMessage.class);
    System.out.println( " "+eventMessage.getOrderId());
    consumerMessage = new ConsumerMessage(eventMessage);
    System.out.println( " consumerMessage "+consumerMessage.getPayload());

}
@Test
void consume() {

    when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString() , any(HttpMethod.class)   ,  
any(HttpEntity.class) ,any(Class.class) , any(String.class) 
)).thenReturn(responseEntity);

    System.out.println( " consumerMessage "+consumerMessage.getPayload());
    OrderDocument orderDocumentactual = 
orderMasterClient.consume(consumerMessage);

    Assertions.assertNotNull(orderDocumentactual);
}
```

}

What is the mistake i am doing . Please help.

Comment: you need to show complete test class

Comment: Did you mock your restTemplate ?

Comment: My Full JUNIT class posted in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in this fashion with mocking a `restTemplate` can lead to unexpected behaviour when the server returns anything other than an actual successfull response. I'd recommend using [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) as this provides for better testing.

If you do want to continue the current approach - you seem to be returning a `responseEntity` which is a mock created by the `@MockBean` annotation. I don't see any code in your question which defines how that mock will behave when someone calls a `getBody()` on it. That could be something to look at. You could either define a real `ResponseEntity` to be returned in your mock, or mock all interactions with `responseEntity`.

Comment: Yes the problem with mocking the getBody method .

Answer (score 1):

In your stubbing, try using`any(OrderDocument.class)` instead of any(Class.class)

Comment: Earlier i added like that and it was not compiling